# Normal "footer not sticking to the bottom" solution not working

Tags: html, css, footer, sticky-footer

I need the web page footer to be positioned at the bottom of the browser window, and not just `position: fixed` so if the window is resized smaller the footer shouldn't go up any further than the bottom of the parent container's content (you'd have to scroll down the window to see the footer there).

The solution I'm most familiar with (below) isn't working for me. Suggestions?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        top content
    </div>
    <footer>
        footer content
    </footer>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body, html { height: 100% }
.container {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.content {
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 36px;
  width: 1000px;
}
footer {
  background: #00a7d4;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  bottom: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 11px;
  height: 36px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 11px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing margin-bottom to padding-bottom:

```
.pageContainer {
  /* margin-bottom: 36px; */
  padding-bottom: 36px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6HrLu/

Works on Chrome.